# JSReact API response won't save to local storage unless preventDefault is applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongoose, local-storage

Have an app that needs to sign in and sign up. Now all the api requests return correctly with the correct data. The problem comes when trying to save returned data to localstorage. When trying to log in, return data  (ie: token) will not save to localstorage, unless e.preventDefault() is applied before `signin` function is called. Now data is pulled from backend but on the client side it will not stay saved to localstorage. After submitting login form localstorage refreshes without anything saving. Now if prevent default is applied it will stay staved correctly. Is there any way to keep local storage token saved without e.preventDefault().

Now I know it does have something to do with api `.then((d)=>{...})` part. if I change it to `.then(localstorage.setItem("token", 1)`. It is perfectly saved without e.preventDefault().

Login.js

```
import { signup, signin } from "../pages/api/index.js";

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleSumbit = (e) => {
    //e.preventDefault(); //if this is applied localstorage token will stay
   signin(form)
      .then((d) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(d.data));
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("error");
      });
  };
```

api.js

```
export const signin = async (data) => {
  return await axios.post("http://localhost:5010/signin/", data);
};
```

backend sign.js

```
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  const email = data.email.trim().toLowerCase();
  const username = data.username;

  const user = await User.findOne({
    $or: [{ email }, { username }],
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "Error / Cannot find User" });
  }

  const valid = await bcrypt.compare(data.password, user.password);
  if (!valid) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "Wrong/Error with Credentials" });
  } else {
    //create and return json web token
    //res.send(jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET));
    return jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To avoid using 'e.preventDefault()', you could consider handling the form submission using the onSubmit attribute rather than onClick. By doing this you can prevent the default form submission without calling e.preventDefault() explicitly. This approach might help you avoid using e.preventDefault()*

```
const handleSumbit = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await signin(form);
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

<form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: So yes, I updated to use the onSubmit instead of onclick. and reworked my handlesubmit. Same error persist. Tired looking up other examples but cant find where the problem is. Definitely on the client side as data from backend is provided. Also note: with the onsubmit change e.preventDefault does not work now.